# How do I sort a list which is composed of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list which has 3 dictionaries.

```
l = [
    {'Index': 3},
    {'Index': 1},
    {'Index': 2}
]

sorted(l, key=lambda l:l['Index'])

print(l)
```

what I expected for answer is

```
[{'Index': 1}, {'Index': 2}, {'Index': 3}]
```

but the actual answer is

```
[{'Index': 3}, {'Index': 1}, {'Index': 2}]
```

where should I fix the code for the answer?

Comment: `sorted` returns an `iterable`. Use `l = sorted(l, key=lambda l:l['Index'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = [
    {'Index': 3},
    {'Index': 1},
    {'Index': 2}
]

newlist = sorted(l, key=itemgetter('Index'))
print(newlist)
```

or just reassign it to itself  like you did it.

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda l:l['Index'])
```

Comment: @Chris Oops! My bad! Thank you